# How to make scrolling for chat app?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

Need auto scroll when new message arrives.

Comment: Are you using any built in component for this? The scrollbar component perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

In ActionScript 3, the TextField object has two properties [`scrollH`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#scrollH) and [`scrollV`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#scrollV) which control horizontal and vertical scroll respectively.

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html

In AS2, the TextField has `hScroll` and `scroll` which control horizontal and vertical scroll respectively.

Check out http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary726.html